# How to draw lines and points on same plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I would like to include both the points from the data frame q and the smoothing function of q, as well as the smoothing function from df1. The plot only returns the points of q. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Rate=rnorm(10, 500, 100), Damage=rnorm(10, 50, 15))
q <- data.frame(R=rnorm(20, 550, 50), V=rnorm(20, 35, 10))

ggplot(df1,aes(x=Rate,y=Damage)) +
#geom_polygon(data=ci,aes(x=x,y=y),fill='gray80') +
geom_point(data=q,aes(x=R,y=V)) +
geom_smooth(aes(col = "GPs"), method="auto",se=FALSE) +
geom_smooth(data=q, mapping=aes(x=R, y=V, col="observed"), 
          method="auto",se=FALSE) +
coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1000), ylim=c(0, 100)) +
theme_bw() +
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 100, 20),) +
labs(subtitle="PPS post-emergence", 
   x = "Rate (mg/Ha)",
   y = NULL) +
scale_color_manual("My legend", values=c("Predicted (GPs)" = "steelblue", 
                                       "Observed (average)" = "firebrick"))
```

Comment: where is the `q` data frame ? you only have `df1` and `x1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your color mapping does not make sense. You have color mapped to 'GPs' and 'observed'. But the values in your color scale do not match these.  You can make it work using

```
ggplot(df1,aes(x=Rate,y=Damage)) +
  geom_point(data=q,aes(x=R,y=V)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(col = "GPs"), method="auto",se=FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(data=q, mapping=aes(x=R, y=V, col="observed"), 
              method="auto",se=FALSE) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1000), ylim=c(0, 100)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 100, 20),) +
  labs(subtitle="PPS post-emergence",
       x = "Rate (mg/Ha)",
       y = NULL) +
  scale_color_manual("My legend", values=c("GPs" = "steelblue",
                                           "observed" = "firebrick"))
```

[image]